# Poll - how many among the users are "professional" historians?

Tags: discussion, users

I'm a bit curious how many people active on this site identify themselves as professional historians.

I know there are some statistics available from when the site entered private BETA, but I assume the set of people has grown since then.

If you're willing to state that you are, I'd appreciate it; especially if you list your area of expertise/concentration/research.

When I say "professional historian" it's somewhat loose - e.g. you hold a degree/concentration in History/Anthropology/related discipline, or you teach it, or you have published works that can be classified as historical research.

P.S. It's mostly idle curiosity about the site demographics, no specific purpose in my asking.

One possible use for the info might be to be able to ask targeted questions aimed at areas where we KNOW we have experts, which should generate high quality answers that would improve the site overall IMHO.

Another one would be for CHAOS team responsible for History SE to see if the site would benefit from extra efforts to attract professionals.

Comment: As a side note - i'm nowhere near a professional.

Comment: I have a BA in History, no real concentration, but I work as a Software Test/Build Engineer.  Go figure...

Comment: NO degree in it, no professional experience in it, just have a decent intrest i where we've been and how we got here. That and "Those that dont' learn from history, are doomed to repeat it" is one of my favourite sayings :p

Comment: one more amateur here

Comment: I have a BA in history with a focus on US Latin-American relations, and I am pursuing a JD so I get more history exposure there too.

Comment: Similar to [canadiancreed](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/users/20/canadiancreed) here. Hated history at school, realised I loved it once I'd left university. I've read _a lot_ since; much of my free time is spent contributing to Wikipedia on mediæval and early modern history, mainly European.

Comment: Professional Software Engineer here. However, I do a lot of reading, and have a fairly extensive library of History at home. In another age (pre-computers) I might have taken that path. However, in another age, we didn't have SE sites either...

Comment: I have a BS in computer science and history (double major). That is my only qualification since I work as a software developer. Specialties include medieval Europe, ancient Rome, the Byzantine Empire, and the Crusades.

Comment: @T.E.D. You might be interested in checking out the [history tag](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bhistory%5d%20closed%3a0) on Programmers.

Comment: Seems like this site is complletely dominated by people working as software developers. (not too surprising given SE's origins, but still).

Comment: Well credentialed in Theology, Hebrew studies, and some Law. But I pay the bills as a code jockey...

Comment: @Vector - seems we all do the latter :)

Answer (score 7):

MA here, with history conferences, articles and even a book to my name... and I'm a professional software developer.

Comment: a real live historian! at least compared to most of us :)

Comment: And I finally managed to answer one of your questions to boot!

Answer (score 1):

Withdrawn doctoral candidate, bunch of conference papers.  Discovered apart from the normal levels of hell for doctoral candidates that are typical; that my research was fundamentally unethical to communicate in a scholarly mode.

Comment: To me, this sounds like a quite often-heard battle-cry, familiar, yet almost requires a more verbose explanation: "my research was fundamentally unethical to communicate in a scholarly mode". (Eg, why not do both? Know sth, tell sth, eg: here?) Unless, by "scholarly" you mean 'strictly required pay-walled gardens' as an outlet ;)

Comment: I researched working class self emancipation techniques. The students you teach are employed as Human Resources Managers, Industrial Relations officers, and Personnel. The primary readers of your research other than scholars are government advisors. One of my research results was that only collective action produces emancipatory knowledge. Another was that the employers and states rapidly use research to attack emancipation or conditions. I would either lie or assist in repressing the object of my research. The *normal levels of hell* were also significant in my withdrawal.

Comment: Sounds familiar again. Without internal description of specifics available, I'd still say: get to the mountaintop, use *all* channels? Dual-use cannot be avoided, but first-mover advantage is a plus? Openness needs to be severely depressed or strangled to foster dystopia.

Comment: I’m choosing to promulgate by alternative channels. And my tenure situation as a manual labourer is vastly superior.